# PyGame Sprites Occasionally Not Drawing

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.x

I am trying to make a basic card game using PyGame. I am currently just trying to draw a single card to the screen. The weird thing is, occasionally it will draw and occasionally it won't. Below is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from socket import *
import sys
import os
import math
import getopt
import random

def load_png(name) :
    # Loads an image and returns the image object
    fullname = os.path.join('/home/edge/Downloads/Playing Cards/PNG-cards-1.3', name)

    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    if image.get_alpha is None :
        image = image.convert()
    else :
        image = image.convert_alpha()

    return image, image.get_rect()

class Card(pygame.sprite.Sprite) :
    def __init__(self, suit, val) :
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.suit = suit
        self.val  = val
        self.image, self.rect = load_png(val + '_of_' + suit + '.png')
        screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = screen.get_rect()
        #self.rect.inflate(-.5, -.5)

def main() :
    pygame.init()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Card Game Thingy')

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (1250, 650) )
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size() )
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill( (0, 0, 0) )

    x = Card('diamonds', '2')
    cardSprite = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(x)

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0) )

    cardSprite.draw(screen)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Game Loop
    while True :
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get() :
            if event.type == QUIT :
                return
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN :
                if event.key == K_DOWN :
                    return

        cardSprite.draw(screen)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "occasionally it will draw and occasionally it won't"? Does it flicker, or do you mean each time you run the script it sometimes displays, and other times it doesn't?

Comment: @Steve
It either draws the image or it doesn't, there is no flicker (IE, the latter). I have experimented with making an event draw it and it never works. This is my first attempt at making anything with PyGame, but I am copying the code almost exactly from [link](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Pygame/Tom's_Pong)

Comment: `if image.get_alpha is None` should be `if image.get_alpha() is None`

Comment: @edge6768 you have to update the display in every loop in the while loop with `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: @cdonts Thank you for pointing that out, I have corrected it.

Comment: @SriHariVignesh I have added that as the last line of the while loop and it is working flawlessly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @edge6768 I will post that as an answer.Please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the display in every loop in the while loop with

```
pygame.display.update()
```